Find last commit that changed a file with a given filename in Git
I have a certain filename and want to find the last (= most recent) commit that changed a file with that file name in Git.
Edit: The file has been deleted in the meantime, so it's not a part of the current working tree.
I've found various threads that find the most recent commit for a specific file in a specific path, however, I'm looking for a way to find files with that filename in any path in the repository.

git log -n 1 -- **/<filename> <filename>
or
git rev-list -1 <commit> -- **/<filename> <filename>
git log and git rev-list allow you to provide glob patterns. These glob patterns will match against the files of the checked commit not against your current working directory. This means it will find the right commit even if you deleted the file.
Similar question for a specific file in a specific path.
git log will provide more detail and can be customized, git rev-list will only provide you with the commit id. See this answer for more details on git rev-list.
Customize git log with --pretty=format:%H to only show the commit hash like git rev-list like in this answer.

Works like a charm - thank you!

My pleasure, thank you for accepting my answer. I joined just yesterday and thus this is a first for me.

Nice second answer ;)

git log $filename.
and if you want only the latest change of each file. try git log -1 $filename.

I had to use git log -- $filename to make it run. However, it doesn't find anything - does it work if the file is not currently part of the working tree anymore because the file has been deleted some time ago?

"git log -- $filename" works even though the file has been deleted at local. (but still stay in the repo.)

Yep, the glob pattern part was the missing link.
